# Combinig two generic List

Tags: java, generics, collections

I want to union two generic list and want to produce new list , I am providing my code in a simple format.

```
public class Example{
    public static <E> List<E> union(List<? extends E> a,List<? extends E> b){
        List<Object> es= new ArrayList<Object>();
        for( E e:a){
            es.add(e);
        }
        for( E e:b){
            es.add(e);
        }
        return (List<E>) es;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Long> a=new ArrayList<Long>();
        a.add(1L);

        List<Integer> b=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        b.add(2);

        List<Number> list3=union(a, b);//Compilation Error due to mismatch of return type

        List<String> a1=new ArrayList<String>();
        a1.add("H");
        List<String> a2=new ArrayList<String>();
        a1.add("=E");

        List<String> a3=union(a1, a2);//no compilation error
    }
}
```

My requirements is I should able to combine two integer and long list to produce a number list and I should able to combine other type as well.
The problem is here is about the return type when I am trying combine the integer and long list. What changes should i need to make to make my code work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your `List<Number> list3=union(a, b);` to `List<? extends Number> list3=union(a, b);` and that should work

and if i can suggest something, create your list as generic `List<E> es= new ArrayList<E>();`, so you don't have to cast it before return

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you use `addAll` ?

```
   public static <E> List<E> union(List<? extends E> a,List<? extends E> b){
        List<E> es= new ArrayList<E>();
        es.addAll(a);
        es.addAll(b);
        return es;
    }
```

And use it like this

```
List<? extends Number> list = union(a, b);
```

Comment: You should use addAll since addAll might be overriden by a subclass of Collection to improve the add all process. Take a look at the java.util.ArrayList.addAll() for example. It does add all elements by using System.arraycopy(). this is very fast if both collections are ArrayLists, e.g. arrayList1.addAll(arrayList2). Thus addAll is not just a simple iteration over a collection and add the elements to another collection. +1 for your answer

Answer (score 1):

The case is that compiler can not find valid type to be resolved, but you can help him

```
List<Number> union = Example.<Number>union(intList, longList);
```

If you do not want to do this just do

```
List<? extends Number> union = Example.union(intList, longList);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways:

1)

```
List<Number> list3 = Example.<Number>union(a, b);
```

2)

```
List<? extends Number> list3 = union(a, b); //You can't add more objects to this list
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static List<Number> union(List<? extends Number> a, List<? extends Number> b) {

    List<Number> es = new ArrayList<Number>();
    for (Number e : a) {
        es.add(e);
    }
    for (Number e : b) {
        es.add(e);
    }
    return es;
}
```

Comment: I can't make it Number , I need to support for other as well like String

Comment: then it's almost like you need to just join lists together into one List of Object. replace "? extends Number" by "?" and List<Number> to List<Object>

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public static <E> List<? extends E> union(List<? extends E> a, List<? extends E> b) {
    HashSet<E> set = new HashSet<E>();
    set.addAll(a);
    set.addAll(b);
    return new ArrayList<E>(set);
}
```

This in a Union it needs to hold the common elements of both list occurring one and the uncommon elements too. `HashSet` holds the unique elements.

Test:

```
public static void main(String... a) {
    List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    l1.add(Integer.valueOf(0));

    List<Long> l2 = new ArrayList<Long>();
    l2.add(Long.valueOf(1));

    List<? extends Number> l3 = union(l1,l2);
    System.out.println(l3);
}
```